# How to use .htaccess to redirect traffic between two Laravel deployments based on condition

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, web-hosting

I have a fundamental problem. I am deploying a module for a web application where the application already exists. The existing application is running on Laravel 5.6 while I am trying to deploy the new module on Laravel 6. 
I personally don't want to tamper with the existing application. I prefer to deploy the new module as another Laravel application. 
What I have done so far is to deploy the new module at the root and the existing one in a folder labelled "EN".
I have tried the following commands in the .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ secureurlhere/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-path/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/anotherpath/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/stillanotherpath/$
RewriteRule .* myurl/EN/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/EN/public/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I expect it to do the following:

1. Redirect all traffic from http:// to https://
2. Any traffic that is not going to /first-path, /anotherpath or /stillanotherpath to be redirected to mydomain/EN/path

However, I see that traffic to /first-path,/anotherpath, stillanotherpath do not redirect to the /EN/path as I expected.

I will appreciate any guide to getting this working right.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume the main issue here is the URL redirects, so that's all I've configured. If you replace your current blocks of redirects with this it should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/first-path [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/anotherpath [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/stillanotherpath
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myurl/EN/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

You can test it in action here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=aebb5858-a512-5b79-98fb-f2aa3c28da95